# Sql Filestream Timeout - Inserting huge files and still be able to run queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

[System processes is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiZ2A.jpg)

I have a small problem.. okay huge problem.

I have a SQL database that has uses a filestream to store huge files (10GB+). When using the sqlfilestream API to copy large files into the database the table becomes unresponsive until the sql connection has been closed.

Now, normally this wouldn't be an issue since normally the connection would only be open long enough to send the query and get the response but when uploading a 10GB file the connection is open for several minutes and so the table does not response to queries until the other connection has been closed.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this? It isn't possible to copy part of the file and then close the connection and then restart because this creates multiple files and would take up a lot of extra space.

Comment: Have you tried using SQL (instead of SqlFileStream) to upload the data into FILESTREAM? Or, have you, by any chance, tried storing the data in BLOB (i.e. varbinary(max)) instead of FILESTREAM?

Comment: Storing as a BLOB would actually store the files in the database file itself, as a result I would have a database file that would be terabytes in size. This would seriously hinder the performance. If I just insert the data in the same way that I insert text, then I would still have the same problem because copying the information over would still take minutes, where the server wouldn't respond. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: BLOBs would grow your database size (and reduce the filesystem size at the same time), but you can partition to multiple disks if that's a problem. Also don't be so sure about performance - "BLOBs are slow" may or may not be true depending on the workload. Anyway, if the problem is due to some kind of blocking behavior, it may be worth trying to avoid it. If the blocking is in SqlFileStream API, it may be worth using a different API (SQL in this case). If the blocking is in FILESTREAM, it may be worth using a different storage mechanism altogether (BLOBs in this case).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - the SQL Server `max` datatypes support BLOBs up to 2GB. Since the OP's files are larger than this, BLOBS won't be a suitable solution.

Comment: @EdHarper Fair point, although there are ways around that ("chunking" the data into multiple BLOBs).

Comment: @ChristopherVickers, I would expect the table to be available during the operation.  Is the issue that queries are trying to access the same row being updated? Perhaps query/index tuning can avoid that. You might consider FileTable to avoid the need to use SqlFileStream, using standard file system APIs instead.

Comment: There's been some interesting ideas here: - Having a separate file table would possibly be a solution but it is far from ideal. I wanted to have the files actually stored inside the same table (as a filestream). Chunking the data would be a very convoluted idea since retrieving would involve getting information from multiple files.

Comment: I suggest you use sp_WhoIsActive to take a look at the table activity during this time. Two things to consider: 1. Is the file inserted from a remote location - can you try copying the file locally to somewhere on the SQL Server then insert it? 2. Maybe the table is locked incorrectly and forcing row level locks would help. Just ideas really, but using sp_WhoIsActive will help illuminate why the table is locked (i.e. if it's incorrectly taking out a table lock)

Comment: The answer to this was to use Isolation.Snapshot when configuring the Sql in C#. This enables snapshot to be used to check queries, which removes the delay.